# Set filname by id generated by mongoose using multer node js

Tags: node.js, express, postman, multer

I am new in Node js `API` and I'm trying to upload an Image using `multer` + `express` + `mongoose` + `postman`

CODE:

```
        var storage = multer.diskStorage({
            destination: function (request, file, callback) {
                callback(null, 'public/images/course');
            },
            filename: function (request, file, callback) {
                return callback(null, file.originalname) 
            }
        });

    var upload = multer({storage : storage})

router.post('/course', upload.single('thumbnail'),async(req, res) => {
    try{
        var course = new Course({
            name : req.body.name,
            thumbnail : "placeholder" // set to path where file is uploaded
        })
        await course.save()
        res.status(201).send(course)
    }catch(e){
        res.status(400).send(e)
    }
})
```

I use postman to post request using `form data` and it creates an image with its originalFilename but i want the filename to be id generated by mongoose and i have seen somewhere that i can use filesystem for that but is there any way i can upload file after id is generated because when i do like this

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (request, file, callback) {
        callback(null, 'public/images/course');
    },
    filename: function (request, file, callback) {
        if (request.data) {
            console.log(file)
           // TODO: consider adding file type extension
           fileExtension = file.originalname.split('.')[1]
           return callback(null, `${request.path}-${request.data._id.toString()}.${fileExtension}`);
        }
        // fallback to the original name if you don't have a book attached to the request yet. 
        return callback(null, file.originalname) 
    }
});

var upload = multer({storage : storage}).single('thumbnail')

router.post('/course',(req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
    const course = new Course({
                name : req.body.name,
                thumbnail : req.body.name
            })
            //console.log(course)
            req.data = course
            //console.log(req.file)
            upload(req, res, function (err) {
                if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
                  // A Multer error occurred when uploading.
                } else if (err) {
                  // An unknown error occurred when uploading.
                }

                // Everything went fine.
              })
})
```

Then i got request body empty.
Thanks in advance

Comment: The request object wouldn't contain Mongoose properties, unless youve set them in Postman, but that would require knowledge of the ID to be generated. The way I often solve this, is create the file temporarily, process the request and store the file metadata, then move that file permanently (normally to S3/GCS), but this may be an option? Have you tried any other ways of getting this to work?